# Nuget Powerpacks Visual Basic mit .Net Framework kompatible machen

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022

ich würde gerne wissen wie ich mit Nuget Microsoft Powerpacks Visual Basic mit dem Framework von Visual Studio 2022 Kompatible machen kann. vllt könnt ihr mir da helfen.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/534171/where-can-i-find-the-download-location-for-microso.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/793814/visual-basic-powerpacks-for-vs2022-basic-shapes-to.html) and [offical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488277(v=vs.120)#reference) we can see that Visual Basic Power Packs are deprecated and not supported anymore.

If you need an alternative to Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs you can try this package “System.Drawing.Common”. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288928/are-there-alternatives-to-the-microsoft-visual-basic-power-packs) hope it can help you.